# Can one learn Mishnah out of order?

Tags: mishna, siyum

I cannot remember ever attending a siyum of an order of the Mishna where the person making the siyum did not learn the last mishna of the last masechta of the seder. Is there some problem with learning the masechtot out of order or the mishnayot of a masechta out of order?

Assuming there is no problem, is it the common practice to learn the last Mishna of the seder at the siyum even if the masechtot were learned out of order? Or is my experience not representative?

Comment: Your experience is not representative of my experience FWIW.

Comment: This erev Pesach the shul finished Seder Moed (Mishna) with Psachim.

Comment: Considering that there are common circumstances where the last mishna in a masechta isn't even a MISHNA (see: Avos, Bechoros, etc.), then why couldn't you end at the second to last perek? It's... unusual to end a masechta in the middle (maybe someone else learned the second half?), but it's pretty common to pick a thematically relevant masechta to end the siyum on...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Oh my! You raised an interesting point about "Pirkei Avot", which spurs me to ask a separate question about making a siyum on this!

Comment: very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92955

Comment: @AlBerko when editing posts, please don't change the spelling/capitalization of the OP.

Comment: Why? It's extremely confusing with Hebrew words, a capitalized word clearly points to a term, which makes reading and understanding faster and more efficient. I think

Comment: @AlBerko it may be easier for you, but it's incorrect grammatically. Italics would be appropriate, but that's a stylistic choice up to the poster.

Comment: Related: is-siyum-masechet-celebration-a-mere-endorsement https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104898/is-siyum-masechet-celebration-a-mere-endorsement

Answer (score 1):

1. Many Yeshivahs indeed learn Mesechtos (e.g. Kiddushin) not in the order of the Gemmorah, as it jumps from one subject to another and gets back to the first.
2. It is customary to repeat the last lines, even if one already learned them to show that he actually completes a whole Maseches. If one was reading the last words of the first Mishnah, that would seem very confusing.

Comment: Do you have a source for #2? I have witnessed and made siyumim out of order where the last lines of whatever needed to be finished were read at the siyum.