# siyum masechet when learning chapters in arbitrary order

Tags: torah-study, siyum

Is it possible to make a siyum masechet when learning the chapters in an arbitrary order? For example if i learn the last chapter before the first?

Comment: very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60729

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In B'Tzel Ha'Chochmo (2/28) Rav Stern writes [and brings a proof] that one can make a siyum for a mesechta they completed, regardless of the the order it was learnt in. [However, he suggests leaving over the end to make the siyum.] Rav Chaim Kinyevsky quoted in יומא טבא לרבנן (pg. קז) says that people are lenient with this. The  Minchas Yitzchok (2/93/5) also concludes that it is a Seudas Mitzvah.

Comment: What is a reason to be strict?

Comment: Non of these sources bring a reason that it shouldn't count as a siyum.

Comment: It is somewhat common to learn chapters of Masechtot non-sequentially. I did this a few times in elementary and high school, and, in one place, we made a siyum.