# In which order should Mesechtos be learned?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

Are there any sources that state for a fact that one should one learn one mesechta before another? Or that perhaps one mesechta is more praiseworthy to learn then the other?

Comment: ואמר רבי ישמעאל: הרוצה שיחכים - יעסוק בדיני ממונות, שאין לך מקצוע בתורה יותר מהן, והן כמעיין הנובע". (בבא בתרא קעה ע"ב

Comment: If there's a natural order of the Masechtos, why would you assume, in the first place, that they should not be learned in that order? THis is the order of Daf-a-Day and all Rabbis learn it in that order - so why not?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60729/can-one-learn-mishnah-out-of-order

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86601/no-divine-form-for-the-oral-law